# MongoDB find in Arrays and objects with several nesting levels

Tags: arrays, mongodb, nested

I try to match a document in this nested structure, it works for one level but not for the second level:

```
{
 type:"example"
 level1:[
          {
            name:"Bill"
            level2:[
                     {
                       skill:"gardening"
                     },
                     {
                       skill:"carpentry"
                     }
            ]

           },

          {
            name:"John"
            level2:[
                     {
                       skill:"painting"
                     },
                     {
                       skill:"acrobatics"
                     }
            ]

          }
        ]

}
```

I can match the first level array, for example:

```
db.collection.find({"level1.name":{$eq:"Bill"}})
```

But if for example I want to math the document with the skill field equal to "acrobatics" I do:

```
db.collection.find({"level1.level2.skill":{$eq:"acrobatics"}})
```

Does not work, any idea?
(sorry if the naming of the example does not make much sense, but that's the structure that I'm facing).

Thank you!

Comment: it is working https://mongoplayground.net/p/goQq_Hs55Z2

Comment: You are correct, it works, not sure what happened, may be the Compass Studio or maybe my brain, thanks.

Comment: exactly what was your question? query is not working or you need whole structure in result? you can update your question first.

Comment: It's returning the whole structure because the collection only has 1 document, which matches the query.

Comment: So you need to get level2 which matches "acrobatics", right?

Comment: @Mapin you can project in find using `$` check this https://mongoplayground.net/p/1hl2l3CGKPb

Comment: @turivishal `$` in projection will return the first element of an array if matches, if i'm not wrong.

Comment: I previously edited my first reply to you(sorry) but you just replied already, you were correct, my query is valid, thanks!

Comment: @varman yes you are right, this is helpful only in unique value, and for multiple match there is a only option is aggregation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are multiple ways you can do this. You can try something like this.

1. `$unwind` to flatten the first level array
2. `$match` to match the element that you need
3. `$group` to group back to the same level

Shell query is given below

```
[
  {
    "$unwind": "$level1"
  },
  {
    $match: {
      "level1.level2.skill": "acrobatics"
    }
  },
  {
    "$group": {
      _id: "$_id",
      level1: {
        "$addToSet": "$level1"
      }
    }
  }
]
```

Working [Mongo playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/FHc4gTtGJX5)

Comment: Thanks, I'll have to do pipelines for fast classification as well:)

Comment: So you can easily do with `$match` stage.

Comment: @varman you can use `$push` instead of `$addToSet`, because `$addToSet` will replace   the same object, look https://mongoplayground.net/p/NKMZOvnrYlv